# Convert Array of objects to Array in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have this data inside my controller form:

```
 $scope.reports = [
            {
                departuredate:"2015-03-10",
                routeline:"PASAY - CAGAYAN",
                seatingtypescode:"ABS",
                tickettripcode:"3",
                tripcodetime:"16:30:00"
            },
            {
                departuredate:"2015-03-10",
                routeline:"PASAY - CAGAYAN",
                seatingtypescode:"ABS",
                tickettripcode:"3",
                tripcodetime:"16:30:00"
            }
          ];
```

The above data is array of objects, I want them to convert in array. I used this code below to convert them in array:

```
var details=[];

        for(var index in $scope.reports){
            var tripcode = $scope.reports[index].tickettripcode;
            var dateOfDepature = $scope.reports[index].departuredate.split('-');
            details.push(tripcode, dateOfDepature[2]);
        }
if(details[tripcode][dateOfDeparture[2]]){
    details[tripcode][dateOfDeparture[2]] = details[tripcode][dateOfDeparture[2]] +1;
}
else {
    details[tripcode][dateOfDeparture[2]] =1;
}
```

The code is not working fine with me and I do not know why. I have a doubt if I am doing array manipulation in a right way. I have error `dateOfDeparture is not defined`. I already defined the `dateOfDeparture` so why I getting this error. I just wanted to get the output which looks like this:

```
    details = Array (
                [3] =>Array
                (
                    [10] =>2
                )
    )
```

The `[3]`is tickettripcode and `[10]` is the day of depaturdate. The 2 means number of departuredate in that date.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
This is the link of my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/n1bw2u36/
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Update your question with the object that you want to be the result of your function so we can better understand what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are a lot of things you should learn about javascript.

By the way, I would expect that you will get what you want with the code like this.

```
var reports = [
    {
        departuredate:"2015-03-10",
        routeline:"PASAY - CAGAYAN",
        seatingtypescode:"ABS",
        tickettripcode:"3",
        tripcodetime:"16:30:00"
    },
    {
        departuredate:"2015-03-10",
        routeline:"PASAY - CAGAYAN",
        seatingtypescode:"ABS",
        tickettripcode:"3",
        tripcodetime:"16:30:00"
    }
];

var table = {};

for (index=0; index<reports.length; index++){

    var tripcode = reports[index].tickettripcode;
    var dateOfDepature = reports[index].departuredate.split('-');
    var date = dateOfDepature[2];

    var map = table[tripcode];
    if (map===undefined){
        map = {};
        table[tripcode] = map;
    }

    if (map[date]===undefined){
        map[date] = 0;
    }

    map[date]++;

}
```

You can use "table" like this.

```
console.log(table);
console.log(table[3][10]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes you are right I need to learn more in javascript. :-)

Comment: Everyone started from beginner! You will be the same if you keep on learning.

Comment: Hello Yazaki. I have a question, why when I changed the following `var table = {};` and `map = {};` to `var table = []` and `map = [];`. I get the undefined error?

Comment: Which line did you get the undefined error? Could you setup plnkr or something?

Comment: Hello Yazaki this is the link of my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ftvskpeu/1/.Try to run it, I console log the `table`. I get the undefined error when I changed them to `[]`. Thanks

Comment: The first fiddle was not saved so I created a new one. http://jsfiddle.net/yybvya9a/2/ thanks

Comment: I could get no error even if I changed {} to [] on your fiddle... Would you like to show me the new one which cause the undefined error?

Comment: Have you seen the console log?

Comment: I have a question again what if I want to push data inside the object. For example I want to push `routline`. The output will be `{ 
 1:{
    2:3,
    routeline:"PASAY - CAGAYAN"
   }
}`

Comment: I could see no error in the console log of my Chrome.
It depends on the browser you use whether the error will occur or not.

Anyway you can't change {} to [] simply because {} is hashmap and [] is array. These are different object. 
Therefore If you want to change the type of object, you should convert it after building 'table' instead of changing the type of 'table'.

It's your homework. :)

Comment: Hello Yazaki. I tried it in google and you are right again :-). There is no undefined data. The undefined data is caused of my browser. I am using Mozilla and I console log the data using firebug. . Thank you for clarifying these things to me. :-) Thank you very much again.